# Installing TensorFow Data Validation on Jetson AGX (AArch64)

Tags: tensorflow-data-validation

Has anyone been able to install TFDV on a Jetson AGX or similar device with AArch64 architecture? I have tried installing with PyPI, building with Docker, and building from source with no luck. I am starting to think it may not be supported and if anyone can confirm this.

Comment: Did you figure out how to build TFDV on aarch64?

Comment: Can you take a look at this [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/issues/141#issuecomment-704409676) from an issue in TFDV repo, which says `TFDV is not supported for aarch64`. Thanks!